# Embeding Youtube video inside a SwiftUI view?

Tags: youtube, swiftui

I would like to embed video from YouTube inside my iOS App who is written only with swiftUI, but I don't know what is the correct way. somebody could help me please ?

With UIKit it is ok, thanks to Youtube helper, but in SwiftUI I have no idea to do it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a webview to your project, then embed an iFrame inside it. Youtube has abandoned the pod project for youtube-helper-ios-sdk and a native library is no longer supported.